# Dynamically referencing a page number?

Tags: page-numbering

I am revising a paper submitted to a journal. In the response letters to the reviewers, I would like to state on which page can they found the changes which they suggested.

The paper will go through another round of the revision with the coauthors and it's likely that the page numbers will change. I would like to avoid having to revise the response letters to the reviewers to have it match the presumably new page numbers.

I am wondering if it's somehow possible to dynamically reference the page number in a similar manner to how you can reference figures and tables. It would be great if there was a command like `\citepage{label}` where I could just input the label of that page and not worry if the number changes. However, I couldn't find any command which would allow that. Is there something like this out there?

Comment: Mostly you will be required to compile the source file of the main paper first and then run the response-file. Without running the original and changed file it looks difficult to me. I don't think such a data can be accessed from PDFs directly (at least, as of now). If you are open to compile the main source first (where you have dynamic pages) and then compile the new file, then I can show you a way. Also if you are open to use LuaLaTeX, that would be a plus. I already have a working mechanism which can be re-utilized for this purpose.

Comment: You can use `\label{key}` and `\pageref{key}`

Comment: @ManuelCart I guess OP is trying to print page numbers from another LaTeX file. Simply using `\label`-`\pageref` won't work in that case.

Comment: If the issue is, as Niranjan suggests, that you have two separate files, one for the response letter and one for the manuscript, you can get cross-document references using the [xr](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr?lang=en) package. It would however help to clarify exactly what your issue is.

Comment: He could use the `xr` package to automatically update the page numbers.  (Still have to re-compile.  Unless they are entangled on a quantum level,)

Comment: @WillieWong thanks, I wasn't aware about the `xr` package. @JohnKormylo can you please clarify entangling on a quantum level?